# Inheriting from public vs private class C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, public

So let's say I've got 2 classes like this :

> Shape

```
class Shape
{
private:
    //private members

public:
    //public members
};
```

> Triangle

```
class Triangle : Shape
{
private:
    //private members
public:
    //public members
};
```

What is the difference between `class Triangle : public Shape` and `class Triangle : Shape` if there's any ?

Comment: not sure if that is in the duplciate: When using the keyword `class` the default access specifier is `private` (`public` when using the keyword `struct`). The rest is explained in the duplicate